# param is missing or the value is empty: name -what exact value to put in require

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know there is so much docs regarding `params.require()` and I have indeed tried every possible ways to debug the error but its unavoidable -whatever I put in `require`, it still gives the same error!

> Here is the error,

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing in UserCrudController#update

Request
Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"patch",
 "authenticity_token"=>"QknxMRZg8aFEkOatw9uxulLUSiEUXgBFQ4iFbbJHIfgvGCtTq2oI3FI7W8eq5Eqeo3Z3dEPWK2IK2XH96f4faQ==",
 "user_crud"=>{"name"=>"Chow", "email"=>"ac@gmail.com"},
 "commit"=>"Update User",
 "id"=>"4"}
```

> And my Controller section:

```
class UserCrudController < ApplicationController

  def update
    # Find a new object using form parameters
    @users = UserCrud.find(params[:id])

    # Update the object
    if @users.update_attributes(users_params)
      # If save succeeds, redirect to the show action
      flash[:notice] = "UserCrud updated successfully."
      redirect_to(user_crud_path(@users))
    else
      # If save fails, redisplay the form so user can fix problems
      render('edit')
    end
  end

  def edit
    @users=UserCrud.find(params[:id])
  end

  def users_params
    params.require(:name).permit(:name, :email,:created_at,:updated_at)
  end
```

> I am using the model as:

```
class UserCrud < ApplicationRecord
    validates_presence_of :name
    validates_presence_of :email
end
```

> Now the View is (edit.html.erb):

```
<% @page_title = "Update User" %>

<%= link_to("<< Back to List", user_crud_path, :class => 'back-link') %>

<div class="users edit">
  <h2>Update User</h2>

  <%= form_for(@users) do |f| %>

    <%= render(:partial => 'form', :locals => {:f => f}) %>

    <div class="form-buttons">
      <%= f.submit("Update User") %>
    </div>

  <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make following changes in your controller,

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user_crud).permit(:name, :email)
end
```

As your `params` contains form inputs under `user_crud` key.

Comment: it works-can you please clarify exactly what parameter to put there , docs are confusing me ?

Comment: @user9185187 Your model is `UserCrud` so form will submit params inside key `user_crud` which is needed to be permitted using `params.require(:user_crud)`

Comment: @user9185187 You can use `params.require(:user_crud).permit!` if you are sure to permit all fields to be permitted.

Comment: ok , that means I need to give the current model name in require()? and if the model name is multi-word then I need to break it down with underscores- Have I understood it correctly?

Comment: @user9185187 yes correct, no need to break, it mostly look like its conventional table name or you can inspect it through params :)

Comment: @ray no, there's no use of model name. Controller knows nothing about the model when submitting a form, so hash name in `params` is constructed after controller's name, you can read details [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html)

Comment: ok that means it is the controller's name (divided by underscore in case of multi word) to be put in require() method , right? @LyzardKyng

Comment: yes, but let me clarify a bit. Rails uses [Convention over Configuration paradigm](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails/Getting_Started/Convention_Over_Configuration), so it requires less code when you follow the rules. Controller name should be in plural form, so in your case (_I think_, it's up to you of course) controller should be named simply `UsersController`, its source then should be in `users_controller.rb`, model will be `User` and db table `users`. Then `params` submitted by the view will include `user` hash (in singular) because you edit and update single entity.

Comment: _continued_ Controller actions that operate with single object (new, edit, update) and corresponding view/partial should use `@user` variable, whilst index action should use `@users`. The former `find` looks up model by `:id` and, because it is a primary key, there'll be no more than one user. The latter usually use `Model.all`. So _programming_ language resembles very close to _natural_ language.

Answer (score 2):

```rb
def user_params
  params.require(:user_crud).permit(:name, :email,:created_at,:updated_at)
end
```

Comment: yes it works, but same question what exactly to put there with respect to my view and controller code

Answer (score 0):

You have to change this code:

```
def users_params
  params.require(:name).permit(
    :name, :email,:created_at,:updated_at
  )
end
```

to

```
private
def user_params
  params.require(:user_crud).permit(:name, :email)
end
```

in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Just to explain, when setting your "resource_params", requiring a param will search for the root of your json. For example:

```rb
def resource_params
  params.require(:foo).permit(:bar)
end
```

Your JSON should looks like this:

```
{
  "foo": {
    "bar": 123
  }
}
```